# Applescript play track does not add to "Up Next"

Tags: itunes

I'm having an issue with the play command.  It seems that if I use this command to play a song within a playlist, it will play that song and then stop.

What I'm seeing is that it will play that song but the "Up Next" queue will be empty.  If the queue is not empty, it will play the next song in the queue and not the next song in the playlist.  The only way to get this to work is by manually double clicking on the song.

My goal is to start playing a playlist from a specific song specified by a variable.

Any ideas?

I'm running OS X 10.10 and iTunes 12.

Comment: Did you check [Doug's Applescripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/)? - usually if it can be done, you can find it there.

Comment: Actually no idea at all.We do not know what script you are using !